# How to run a command within a subprocess in Python script?

Tags: python, subprocess, putty

I'm trying to run a script that runs putty and within the putty terminal that gets created, run a command. I've been able to start putty from my script using Python's subprocess module with check_call or Popen. However, I'm confused as to how I can run a command within the subprocess Putty terminal from my script. I need to be able to run this command in putty and analyze its output on the Putty terminal. Thanks for any help.

Comment: What are you doing with putty? It might be a better idea to do the task directly from a python script (for example, to execute remote commands via SSH you could use paramiko).

Comment: I'm not sure what your requirements are, but you can ssh and give commands at the same time: `ssh systemsboy@rhost.systemsboy.edu 'ls -l; ps -aux; whoami'` with more info [here](http://malcontentcomics.com/systemsboy/2006/07/send-remote-commands-via-ssh.html)

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the `stdin` argument to `PIPE` and use the `communicate` function of `Popen` to send data to stdin.

```
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE

p = Popen('/the/command', stdin=PIPE, stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE)
std_out, std_err = p.communicate('command to putty')
```

That being said, it may be easier to use a python library that implements the `ssh` protocol (like `paramiko`) rather than going through putty.

Comment: I would consider this to be 1.  A link only answer. 2. Not particularly helpful since OP seems to already know how to start an external program (`putty`) using `Popen`.  The problem isn't opening `putty`, the problem is getting `putty` to do what OP wants once it is opened...